# Convex bottom bar icons doesn't change to home menu when i press back ( flutter )

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

There is a problem in (Convex Bottom Bar dependency in flutter).

Every thing is working fine, and icons changes correctly between pages, but when I press on back button to return from favourite page as example to home page, The page change fine to home, but icon is still stand on the same favourite page and does not change to home icon also!

This is making A confuse while using, and i don't know what is the problem? (I know little, and I tried every thing after searching and nothing! ).

I hope I will find the solution here from you, and this is the code details for help.

Thank you for helping.

```
 class DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  PageController? _pageController;
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  late List<Widget> _screens;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _screens = [
      const HomeScreen(),
      const FavouriteScreen(),
      const CartScreen(fromNav: true),
      const MenuScreenNew()
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        bottomNavigationBar:
        ConvexAppBar(
          items:  const [
            TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.favorite, title: 'Like'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.shopping_basket_rounded, title:'Cart'),
            TabItem(icon: Icons.person, title: 'Profile'),
          ],

          initialActiveIndex: _pageIndex,
          onTap: (int index){
            setState(() {
              _pageIndex = index;
            });
          },
        ),
        body:
           PageView.builder(
              controller: _pageController,
              itemCount: _screens.length,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return _screens[_pageIndex];
              },
            ),
      );
  }
```